# Delete unnecessary metatable from WordPress database?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to delete some unnecessary metatable from WordPress database, whenever I log out.
I used the below code, but it does not work. I mean it's not deleting the table which I mentioned.

```
<?php
function delete_useless_post_meta() 
{
  global $wpdb;
  $table = $wpdb->prefix.'postmeta';
  $wpdb->delete ($table, array('meta_key' => '_edit_last'));
  $wpdb->delete ($table, array('meta_key' => '_edit_lock'));
  $wpdb->delete ($table, array('meta_key' => '_wp_old_slug')); 
}
add_action('wp_logout','delete_useless_post_meta');
?>
```

Comment: do you want to delete while admin logout or user?

Comment: @Vel admin. I chaghed it to this`if( current_user_can('editor') || current_user_can('administrator') ){
        global $wpdb;
        $table = $wpdb->prefix.'postmeta';
        $wpdb->delete ($table, array('meta_key' => '_edit_last'));
        $wpdb->delete ($table, array('meta_key' => '_edit_lock'));
        $wpdb->delete ($table, array('meta_key' => '_wp_old_slug'));
    }`  but nothing changed!

Comment: `add_action('wp_logout','delete_useless_post_meta');` this hook working fine for admin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's best not to interact with the database directly, especially when issuing DELETE statements, since a single typo can destroy unintended data. Instead, use WordPress functions to get a list of all user IDs, then remove the user meta field for each user individually, like so:

```html
$all_user_ids = get_users( 'fields=ID' );
foreach ( $all_user_ids as $user_id ) {
    delete_user_meta( $user_id, 'your_meta_key_to_delete' );
}
```

**Function reference:**
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/delete_user_meta

**OR**

Other Option like, you can use the Adminimize plugin - [Adminimize plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/adminimize/)

Answer (score 0):

This has been explained here in full.

[Remove Unnecessary WP Postmeta](https://codepangs.com/delete-unnecessary-post-metadata/)

All you have to do is add the following in your theme functions.php file

```html
function delete_useless_post_meta() {
   global $wpdb;
   $table = $wpdb->prefix.'postmeta';
   $wpdb->delete ($table, array('meta_key' => '_edit_last'));
   $wpdb->delete ($table, array('meta_key' => '_edit_lock'));
   $wpdb->delete ($table, array('meta_key' => '_wp_old_slug')); }
add_action('wp_logout','delete_useless_post_meta');
```